# JSON iOS isEqualToString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to check if a value in my .json file is "0" or "1".

My .json file:

```
{
    "timetable": [
      {
        "50mhour": "1",
        "on": "1"
      },
      {
        "50hour": "2",
        "on": "1"
      },
      {
        "50hour": "50min1",
        "on": "1"
      },
      {
        "techhour": "4",
        "on": "1"
      },
    ]
}
```

I created a method to call this URL:

```
-(void)makeRequests
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://content.app.ch/api/timetable.json"];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
                                         JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                         success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id responseObject)
                                         {

                                             self.get = [responseObject objectForKey:@"timetable"];       
                                         }
                                         failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id responseObject)
                                         {
                                             NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                                         }];

    [operation start];
}
```

And ofcourse, I created a NSDictionary as well

```
NSDictionary *tempDictionary= [self.get objectAtIndex:1];
```

I'm not quite sure about the `objectAtIndex` value.

What is the right way to check if a value is "0" or "1" I know `isEqualToString:` can probably do this but I'm not sure how.

UPDATE:
Tried this as a suggestion from the answers below:

```
NSNumber *obj = [[self.get objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"on"];
int onValue = [obj intValue];

if (onValue == 1) {
    NSLog(@"works!");
}

else {
    NSLog(@"doesn't work!");
}
```

The code works, but the JSON value is "1" and the NSlog still shows "doesn't work!".

Comment: Don't be afraid to make mistakes. Run it and see what happens. Print out values and/or set a breakpoint and walk through it in the debugger.

Comment: The `isEqualToString:` method is for comparing two `NSString` objects. Since you have an `int` you need: `if (onValue == 1) {`.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks, it worked. However I'm still not getting the right value for some reason. It should reply 1 but it doesn't, the JSON file contains 1 for the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON-encoded array you presented (timetable) has only one element, so taking `objectAtIndex:1` would crash your program/throw an out of bounds exception. Get element 0 or `lastObject` from the array and you'll have a pointer to the following dictionary:

```
{
"50hour": "1",
"on": "1"
}
```

Since this is a dictionary, the correct way to look up a value is by key:

```
NSNumber *obj = [[self.get objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"on"]; // or @"50hour", whichever you need
int onValue = [obj intValue];
```

Comment: My JSON file is way lager but all the values are very alike. I tried your code (see updated post) but it doens't work, it replies Bad receiver type Int. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: The value for the "on" key is not an `NSNumber`, it is an `NSString`. Your code only works because `NSString` just happens to have an `intValue` method like `NSNumber`.

Comment: Thanks, with @rmaddy's suggestion the code works, I think my .json file is a bit screwed up, xcode should give me the right message (I've updated me code once again, hope you can take a look).

Comment: Also my JSON files does not contain only one element it contains more if I'm right, see updated post.

Comment: @Timothy, can you see in the debugger/log in the console the value of `[[self.get objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"on"]`?

Comment: @Alexander What should be the right way to NSLog that? I tried `NSLog([[self.get objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"on"]);` but it doesn't show anything in the logs.

Comment: This should do it, and it's interesting that nothing showed up. What about `[self.get objectAtIndex:0]`? And generally `self.get`.

Comment: For some reason they don't report anything although the value is right and xcode gives no build errors.

Comment: Something went wrong with parsing/assigning the value of `get` then. Check your code.

Comment: Not at all, the value even turns green and I copied and pasted it exactly this should be the right code right? `NSLog(self.get);`

Comment: Should be like this, but then if the parsing and assigning was correct, this last NSLog would've displayed a proper value.

Comment: NSLog is still not working, however if I change `if (onValue == "1") {` to `if (onValue == "0") {` It returns a value, although the value in the JSON file is still 1..

Answer (score 0):

The flow of your JSON is like this:

You have the array in JSON and in that array, the first element is dictionary.

You first get the data from JSON directly into an array. Then get the first object of Array into dictionary and then get the value like this

Get the value for On from this code :

`int on = [[[self.get objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"on"] integerValue];`

`int value = [[[self.get objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey@"50hour"] integerValue]`

Comment: If you assign to an `int` variable, use `intValue`. If you use `integerValue` then the variable should have a type of `NSInteger`.